# How run cherrypy app without screen logging?

Tags: cherrypy

Hi I looking for some configuration or flag that allows me to silence the requested pages.

When I run `python cherrypy_app.py` and I join to the `127.0.0.1:8080` in the console where I start the cherrypy app show me

`127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2014:19:10:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1512 "" "Mozilla/5.0 ..."
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2014:19:10:35] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 88 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 ..."
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2014:19:10:36] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406 "" "Mozilla/5.0 ..."`

I do not want to show this info. It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I as far as I remember in my first attempts with CherryPy I had the same desire. So here's a little more to say besides turning off the stdout logging per se.

CherryPy has some predefined [environments](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html?#environments): staging, production, embedded, test_suite that are defined [here](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/4939ea9fbe6b0def376fbb349c039c38b0a8994b/cherrypy/_cpconfig.py?at=default#cl-187). Each environment has its set of configuration. So while developing stdout logging is in fact quite helpful, whereas in production environment it makes no sense. Setting the environment according to the deployment is the correct way to deal configuration in CherryPy.

In your particular case the stdout logging is controlled by `log.screen`. It is already disabled in production environment.

Here's the example, but note that setting environment inside your application isn't the best idea. You're better use [`cherryd`](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#cherryd)'s `--environment` for it instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cherrypy


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8,
    # Doing it explicity isn't a recommended way
    # 'log.screen' : False
  }
}

class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return 'Logging example'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Better use cherryd (http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#cherryd) 
  # for setting the environment outside the app
  cherrypy.config.update({'environment' : 'production'})

  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Comment: thx @saaj but how I run my app cherrypy_app.py with cherryd. I try `cherryd cherry_app.py` but seems to run but in the webpage are nothing.

Comment: @inye ``cherryd`` should be used mutually exclusive with ``cherrypy.quickstart`` because they basically do the same thing in different use-cases. I mean code inside ``if __name__ == '__main__'`` and outside of it. So in my example add ``cherrypy.tree.mount(App(), '/', config)`` after ``App`` class and try again. E.g. ``cherryd -e production cherry_app.py``.

Comment: @inye No, correct command line is ``cherryd -e production -i cherry_app`` as it does module import rather than module execution.