# Prevent cherrypy from logging access

Tags: python, logging, cherrypy

I'm trying to set up a logger to only catch my ERROR level messages, but my logger always seems to write `INFO:cherrypy.access` messages to my log file, which I dont want. I tried setting the `log.error_file` global, and using the standard python logging module `logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log', filemode='w', level=logging.ERROR)`, but even though I specify the threshold to be ERROR level messages, I still get those INFO level messages written to my log file. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: It's not very practical to configure CherryPy logs with bare `logging`. Make sure you understand CherryPy configuration and its environments (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26288820/2072035)). If you persist, [this article](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2012/logging_tree/) has good explanation of CherryPy `logging` tree and ways to extend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can disable access messages by setting up my own:

`logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log', filemode='w', level=logging.ERROR)`

and then setting:

`cherrypy.log.access_log.propagate = False`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `INFO` level logs are coming for `cherrypy.access` . According to [documentation](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/refman/_cplogging.html) -

> You should set these at either the global level or per application (see next), but generally not both.
>
> **log.screen**: Set this to True to have both “error” and “access” messages printed to stdout.
> **log.access_file**: Set this to an absolute filename where you want “access” messages written.
> **log.error_file**: Set this to an absolute filename where you want “error” messages written.

You should also try setting the `log.access_file` (similar to `log.error_file`) . Or you can add an handler for that, example -

```
from logging import handlers
fname = getattr(log, "rot_access_file", "access.log") #The log for access messsages.
h = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(fname, when='midnight')
h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
h.setFormatter(_cplogging.logfmt)
log.access_file = ""
log.access_log.addHandler(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well and I figured it out. So post it here and hope it can help people had similar questions.

CherryPy version 14.2.0

To disable `access` logging, you can simply leave an empty string as `'log.access_file': ''`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update(
        {
            'server.socket_host': settings.HOST,
            'server.socket_port': settings.PORT,
            'log.screen': True,
            'log.access_file': '',
            'log.error_file': ''
        }
    )

    config = {
        '/': {
            'tools.sessions.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': settings.PROJECT_ROOT
        }
    }
```

Below I post my customized logging configurations `logging_configuration.py`, I added custom logger into the settings:

```
# logger settings
LOGGER_NAME = 'custom'
_LOGGER_HANDLER = 'cherrypy_' + LOGGER_NAME
_MULTIMEDIA_LOGFILE = LOGGER_NAME + '.log'
_ACCESS_LOGFILE = 'access.log'
_ERRORS_LOGFILE = 'errors.log'

LOG_CONF = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'void': {
            'format': ''
        },
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s (%(module)15s:%(lineno)2s) [%(levelname)s] %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        _LOGGER_HANDLER: {
            'level':'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'filename': _MULTIMEDIA_LOGFILE,
            'maxBytes': 10485760,
            'backupCount': 20,
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        },
        'cherrypy_access': {
            'level':'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'void',
            'filename': _ACCESS_LOGFILE,
            'maxBytes': 10485760,
            'backupCount': 20,
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        },
        'cherrypy_error': {
            'level':'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'void',
            'filename': _ERRORS_LOGFILE,
            'maxBytes': 10485760,
            'backupCount': 20,
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        LOGGER_NAME: {
            'handlers': [_LOGGER_HANDLER],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False
        },
        'cherrypy.access': {
            'handlers': ['cherrypy_access'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False
        },
        'cherrypy.error': {
            'handlers': ['cherrypy_console', 'cherrypy_error'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False
        },
    }
}
```

How I use it?

```
import cherrypy
from docs import logging_configuration as loggingconf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update(
        {
            'server.socket_host': settings.HOST,
            'server.socket_port': settings.PORT,
            'log.screen': True,
        }
    )

    cherrypy.engine.unsubscribe('graceful', cherrypy.log.reopen_files)
    logging.config.dictConfig(loggingconf.LOG_CONF)  # add it here

    config = {
        '/': {
            'tools.sessions.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': settings.PROJECT_ROOT
        }
    }
    cherrypy.quickstart(CampPage(), '/', config)
```

To log into cherrypy_custom.log, use:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(loggingconf.LOGGER_NAME)

logger.info('Hello There...')  # this line will be written into cherrypy_custom.log
```

To disable access log, set `_ACCESS_FILELOG = ''` to empty string